# Есть ли короткий вариант произношения отчества "Иович"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Иными словами, произносили ли отчества таких людей просто как *Иыч?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут путаница в понятиях.

Начну с простого. Такие отчества как *Петрович, Львович* и другие с ударной предпоследней гласной не сокращаются в принципе.

Но при этом отчество *Иович* само по себе есть сокращенная форма от *Иовович*. Имя *Иов* имеет конечный согласный - и по общему правилу требует именно такой формы отчества. А имя *"Иова"*, которое порождало бы *Иович* (как *Лука - Лукич, Фома - Фомич* и т. д.) не фиксируется как нормативное.

Однако имена с окончанием на -в (*Ярослав, Пров* и некоторые другие) допускают такую стяженной формы отчества (*Ярославич, Прович*) - степень нормативности такого стяжения надо смотреть в словаре.

"*Иович*" закрепилось во многом благодаря Леониду Иовичу Гайдаю, который был записан именно с таким отчеством вопреки тому, что отец его имел имя *Иов*, не *Иова*.

Таким образом, *Иович* - уже само по себе сокращение от *Иовович* и дальнейшему стяжению не подлежит ни по каким мотивам.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, всё-таки есть полная форма Иовович. А я вчера как раз увидел портрет, видимо, как раз Гайдая именно с таким отчеством, Иович, и решил, что у всех так.

Comment: Дык оно-то может у всех, коли признано нормативным вариантом, но от того не перестало быть стяженной формой. В стяженной форме ударение уже идет на предпоследний слог и дальше сокращать некуда. Но в общем-то и полная форма существует или должна была существовать.

Answer (score 1):

А как это "Иыч" вообще произнести? Отчества сокращают, но так, что бы их можно было восстановить и было удобопроизносимо - Алек**сан**дров**на** -> Санна, **Георг**ов**ич** -> Георгич и т. д.

*Иович* может сократиться лишь до *Йович -> Ёвич*.